# SQL Row_Number() (Partition by… Order By…) IGNORES Order statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, window-functions, row-number

I couldn’t find a function to support what I’m trying to approach.

Let’s suppose we have the following table which contains a field sort order and certain duplicates

```
+----------+----------+-----+-------------+-----------+
| UniqueId |    Id    | Qty | RetailPrice | SortOrder |
+----------+----------+-----+-------------+-----------+
|     3124 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         1 |
|     2627 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         2 |
|     7635 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         3 |
|     8732 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         4 |
|     3791 | 92361725 |  20 |      269.99 |         5 |
|     4328 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         6 |
+----------+----------+-----+-------------+-----------+
```

I want to enumerate my rows increasing their value when a duplicate is found, if not then reset the row number. The result must be shown in the column **rn** the following table if **Qty** is the column to evaluate:

```
+----------+----------+-----+-------------+-----------+----+
| UniqueId |    Id    | Qty | RetailPrice | SortOrder | rn |
+----------+----------+-----+-------------+-----------+----+
|     3124 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         1 |  1 |
|     2627 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         2 |  2 |
|     7635 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         3 |  3 |
|     8732 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         4 |  4 |
|     3791 | 92361725 |  20 |      269.99 |         5 |  1 |
|     4328 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         6 |  1 |
+----------+----------+-----+-------------+-----------+----+
```

I tried to use **ROW_NUMBER()** function but I can’t get the results I want

```
;WITH Table1 AS(
SELECT 3124 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 1 SortOrder UNION ALL
SELECT 2627 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 2 SortOrder UNION ALL
SELECT 7635 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 3 SortOrder UNION ALL 
SELECT 8732 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 4 SortOrder UNION ALL
SELECT 3791 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 20 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 5 SortOrder UNION ALL
SELECT 4328 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 6 SortOrder
)

SELECT UniqueId, Id, Qty, RetailPrice, SortOrder,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Qty ORDER BY SortOrder) rn
FROM Table1
```

```
+----------+----------+-----+-------------+-----------+----+
| UniqueId |    Id    | Qty | RetailPrice | SortOrder | rn |
+----------+----------+-----+-------------+-----------+----+
|     3791 | 92361725 |  20 |      269.99 |         5 |  1 |
|     3124 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         1 |  1 |
|     2627 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         2 |  2 |
|     7635 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         3 |  3 |
|     8732 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         4 |  4 |
|     4328 | 92361725 |  25 |      269.99 |         6 |  5 |
+----------+----------+-----+-------------+-----------+----+
```

The Order By is completely ignored, can anyone help?

Comment: The ORDER BY isn't ignored.   If you partition by Qty, then you group Row 6 with Rows 1-4.   You need to try a "Gaps and Islands" approach.   Look at the LAG function.

Comment: It's not ignored at all. Watch closely. You are partitioning the result based on `Qty` column. Therefore, in the first partition, `rn` is 1. And in next partition, the `rn` is based on `Qty`. What else you want?

Comment: Thanks Tab Alleman but unfortunately this has to be approached in 2008 R2 database Engine as I specify in the tags

Comment: Thank you for putting in the tsql to create the test. We can re-create the lead and lag function by joining this table onto itself with SortOrder +/- 1, however I'm still working on figuring out how to handle a new row after the gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Since you are in 2008 I replicated Lead and Lag by self joining this table on SortOrder +/- 1. I also updated your sample set to account for new islands of Qty 25.

Sorry for the wall of text but I had to update your sample set to add 2 rows to island 3 and create 2 CTEs to get the island ranges.

```
--Updates Sample Set with 3 Islands.
WITH Table1 AS(
SELECT 3124 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 1 SortOrder UNION ALL --Island 1
SELECT 2627 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 2 SortOrder UNION ALL --Island 1
SELECT 7635 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 3 SortOrder UNION ALL --Island 1
SELECT 8732 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 4 SortOrder UNION ALL --Island 1
SELECT 3791 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 20 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 5 SortOrder UNION ALL --Island 2
SELECT 4328 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 6 SortOrder UNION ALL --Island 3
SELECT 4328 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 7 SortOrder UNION ALL --Island 3
SELECT 4328 UniqueId,92361725 Id, 25 Qty, 269.99 RetailPrice, 8 SortOrder           --Island 3
),

--Creating a CTE to get the Lead and Lag since this is 2008. This will allow us to determine if a row is the first or last row of an island.
LeadLagTable AS(
SELECT
    Table1.UniqueId,
    Table1.Id,
    Table1.Qty,
    Table1.RetailPrice,
    Table1.SortOrder,
    LeadTable.SortOrder AS LeadSortOrder,
    LagTable.SortOrder AS LagSortOrder,
    CASE
        WHEN LagTable.SortOrder IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS StartRowFlag,
    CASE
        WHEN LeadTable.SortOrder IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END AS LastRowFlag
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table1 LeadTable ON
    Table1.SortOrder = LeadTable.SortOrder - 1
    AND Table1.Qty = LeadTable.Qty
LEFT JOIN Table1 LagTable ON
    Table1.SortOrder = LagTable.SortOrder + 1
    AND Table1.Qty = LagTable.Qty
),

--With the LeadLagTable we can now get the ranges for each island, as well as a unique ID for each island.
Ranges AS (
SELECT
    RangeStart,
    RangeEnd,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RangeStart) AS RangeRowNum
FROM (
    SELECT
        StartRow.SortOrder AS RangeStart,
        EndRow.SortOrder RangeEnd,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StartRow.SortOrder ORDER BY EndRow.SortOrder) AS rn
    FROM LeadLagTable StartRow
    JOIN LeadLagTable EndRow ON
        StartRow.StartRowFlag = 1
        AND EndRow.LastRowFlag = 1
        AND StartRow.SortOrder <= EndRow.SortOrder
        AND StartRow.Qty = EndRow.Qty
    ) tbl
WHERE rn = 1
)
```

And here is the actual Query.

```
--We now join on the island ranges, and partition by the Island ID.
SELECT
    UniqueId,
    Id,
    Qty,
    RetailPrice,
    SortOrder,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RangeRowNum ORDER BY SortOrder) AS rn
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Ranges ON
    Table1.SortOrder >= Ranges.RangeStart
    AND Table1.SortOrder <= Ranges.RangeEnd
```

Comment: I just realized that this works with the sample data provided but does not scale if you have additional Qty 25 orders with a valid lead/lag. Their rn continues where the previous stopped. Checking.

Comment: Updated the answer. This should work, but depending on the table size, may be memory intensive.

Comment: Yes I have the full scenario here and fits pretty good. Many many thanks for the efforts

Comment: Glad to help. This was a fun problem to work on. If this answers your question then please mark it as the answer.